# Dropdown | Material Design | Two Items | Overlap

Tags: javascript, html, css, material-design

I'm trying to implement only dropdown fields with material design. I've looked into several examples on the internet, however all of them have a particular error. If I have two dropdown items near each other, they overlap.

**Let's follow this example:**

http://codepen.io/sebastianbaumann/pen/bNKReL

```
        <div class="button-group">
        <i id="icon"></i>
        <a id="input" href="">Choose an option</a>
          <ul id="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else </a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Account Settings</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Help and Feedback</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
```

If the dropdown item is replicated, things do not work.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I there,

I've used another library. The problem is related with z-index!

If you want to understand it, this may be the solution:
https://github.com/emilsgulbis/jQuery-material-form-fields/issues/4

Thanks to the author for the library and answer to the issue.